# Efficient way to fill a convex shape

Tags: c++, graphics, opencv, visualization, computational-geometry

Say I have a closed shape as seen in image below and I have the edge pixels. What is the most efficient way to fill the shape, i.e. turn pixels 'on' inside the shape if:

1) I have all the edge pixels

2) I have most of the edge pixels and not all of them (as seen in the figure).

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It all depends on the situation.

If you manually created the framebuffer (basically using a byte array or something alike) you have to iterate over all pixels you want to change. So, for example, starting at the leftmost edge of a row:

- Find start of shape on row
- Jump one right and turn on pixel until found second end of shape on row (or end of row)
- Continue on next row

This will of course only work if you have all edge pixels. Take a look at [Marching Squares](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marching_squares), can be of some assistance.

And please, be more specific. "The most efficient way to fill the shape" depends alot of your underlying rendering library, if it's raster graphics and so on...

**EDIT**
Note, the algorithm is much faster if you can generate the edge pixels, then there's no need to look for start of edge.

Answer (score 4):

Construct the convex hull and add the missing pixels. Then use a scanline algorithm to fill the polygon.

Answer (score 2):

A standard [flood fill](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill) algorithm will be pretty efficient on a convex shape, and will handle the cases where the shape is less convex than you anticipated. Unfortunately it requires an unbroken outline.

Answer (score 1):

1. The breaks in the boundary destroy the meaning if the word "inside".
2. A neural network like a human retina is very efficient at doing this processing.
3. On a computer you need to take time to define what you mean by "inside".  How big a gap?  How wriggerly a boundary?
4. Simulate a largish circular bug bouncing arround the "inside" - too big to go thru the gaps but smaller than the min radius of curvature of the boundary????

Comment: I love the "bug" idea. You could also run it around the outside to provide a second boundary beyond the gaps then fill the inside with another method.

Answer (score 0):

Before you can fill the inside of something you would need to determine the exact boundary, in this case that would constitute recognising the circle.

After that you can just check in a box around the circle for every pixel, if it is actually in it. Since you have to do something with every pixel inside the circle and the number of pixels in the circle is linear in the number of pixels of a bounding square (assuming the bounding square's sides have length 'radius * constant' for some constant), this should be close to optimal.